# Validate select (two out of four)for checking if value is null and their is no duplicate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have generated a combination of select box in which the value of one select box is dependent on another select box ,and it is done by json array(for populating the drop down list ),and there is a way to generate this structure dynamically(to add more than one row of 6 select value).I have implemented that any two of the selected value should not be same but the problem is that the user have to select only two of four select box,and other two of them should be blank.How do i validate both,that is value of select box should not be same (except for two null/blank value ) and user should select only two distinct value(for other  blank should be selected).I am attaching the html and the java script here ..you can also see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajsbxrhq/)

```
<h4> Honours Selection</h4> 
<table class="tg" id="custom-fields">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="col-wide" />
    <col class="col-narrow" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
    <col class="col-normal" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" rowspan="2">
      <br />Honours
    </th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="4">General</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" colspan="2">Bank Transaction Details</th>
    <th class="tg-hgcj" rowspan="2">Add More</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub1</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub2</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub3</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Sub4</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Bank Transaction id</td>
    <td class="tg-093g">Bank Transaction date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <select name="hons[]" id="select1-0" onchange="">
        <option value="Hindi"  >Hindi  </option>
        <option value="Bengali">Bengali</option>
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="History">History</option>
        <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
        <option value="Phylosophy">Phylosophy</option>
        <option value="Sanskrit">Sanskrit</option>
        <option value="Geography (Arts)">Geography (Arts)</option>
        <option value="Economics (Arts)">Economics (Arts)</option>
        <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
        <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
        <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
        <option value="Zoology">Zoology</option>
        <option value="Botany">Botany</option>
        <option value="Geography (Science)">Geography (Science)</option>
        <option value="Economics (Science)">Economics (Science)</option>
        <option value="Accountancy">Accountancy</option>
</select>
      <select id="ddl2" name="session[]">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <select name="sub1[]" id="select2-0">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <select name="sub2[]" id="select3-0">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <select name="sub3[]" id="select4-0">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <select name="sub4[]" id="select5-0">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <input type="text" name="tran_id[]" id="tranid-0" onfocus="checkDuplicatesHons(0)"/>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-30rh">
      <input type="text" name="tran_date[]" />
    </td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Script for adding dynamic row and populating select values using json

```
var x = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addCF").click(function() {
    $("#custom-fields").append([
      '<tr>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<select name ="hons[]" id="' + 'select1-' + x + '">',
        '<option value="Hindi"  >Hindi  </option>',
        '<option value="Bengali">Bengali</option>',
        '<option value="English">English</option>',
        '<option value="History">History</option>',
        '<option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>',
        '<option value="Phylosophy">Phylosophy</option>',
        '<option value="Sanskrit">Sanskrit</option>',
        '<option value="Geography (Arts)">Geography (Arts)</option>',
        '<option value="Economics (Arts)">Economics (Arts)</option>',
        '<option value="Physics">Physics</option>',
        '<option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>',
        '<option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>',
        '<option value="Zoology">Zoology</option>',
        '<option value="Botany">Botany</option>',
        '<option value="Geography (Science)">Geography (Science)</option>',
        '<option value="Economics (Science)">Economics (Science)</option>',
        '<option value="Accountancy">Accountancy</option>',      
      '</select> ',
      '<select id="ddl2" name="session[]"></select>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<select name="sub1[]" id="select2-' + x + '"></select>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<select name="sub2[]" id="select3-' + x + '"></select>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<select name="sub3[]" id="select4-' + x + '"></select>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<select name="sub4[]" id="select5-' + x + '"></select>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class="tg-30rh">',
      '<input type="text" name="tran_id[]" id="tranid-' + x + '"onfocus="checkDuplicatesHons('+x+')""/>',
      '</td>',
      '<td class ="tg-30rh">',
      '<input type="text" name="tran_date[]" />',
      '</td>',
      '<td>',
      '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF">Remove</a>',
      '</td>',
      '</tr>'
    ].join(''));

    $('#select1-' + x).trigger('change');

    x++;
  });
  $("#custom-fields").on('click', '.remCF', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
});

var jsonObj = {
  "Hindi": [
    ["History", "Sociology", "Economics",""], "Philosophy", "Political Science", "English"
  ],
  "Bengali": [
    ["History", "Sociology",""], "Sanskrit", "Philosophy", "Political Science"
  ],
  "English": [
    ["History", "Sociology", "Economics",""], "Philosophy", "Political Science", ["Bengali", "Hindi"]
  ],
  "History ": ["Philosophy", " Political Science", ["Bengali", " Hindi",""], " English"],
  "Political Science": [
    [" History ", " Sociology", " Economics",""], "Philosophy", ["Bengali ", " Hindi",""], "English"
  ],
  "Philosophy": [
    [" History", " Sociology",""], " Sanskrit", "Political Science", ["Bengali", "Hindi",""]
  ]
};

function updateSelect(e) {
  var targetId = e.target.id;
  var id = parseInt(targetId.match(/[\w\d]+\-(\d+)$/)[1], 10);

  var getOpts = function(raw) {
    raw = Array.isArray(raw) ? raw : [raw, ''];

    return raw.map(function(obj) {
      return new Option(obj, obj);
    });
  };

  var newKey = $('#select1-' + id).val();

  var mappings = [2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(map, val, index) {
    var key = '#select' + val + '-' + id;
    map[key] = index;
    return map;
  }, {});

  var selected = jsonObj[newKey];

  $.each(mappings, function (selector, index) {
    $(selector).empty().append(getOpts(selected[index]));
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#custom-fields').on('change', 'select[id^="select1-"]', updateSelect);     
  $('#select1-0').trigger('change'); // For initial page load.
});
```

Script for checking Duplicate

```
function checkDuplicatesHons(id) {
    var k=10+6*parseInt(id);//id of the selectbox for the chacking
    alert(k);
  var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select"),
      i,
      current,
      selected = {};

  for(i = k; i <= k+3; i++){
    //current = selects[i].selectedIndex;

    current = selects[i].options[selects[i].selectedIndex].value;//for selecting actual value
    alert(current);
    if (selected[current]) {
      alert("Each Subject should be selected once.");
      return false;
    } else
      selected[current] = true;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This is a solved problem. Instead of rolling your own solution you might want to use a library. For example this one: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Comment: thanks,for the library, but i need to customize as per my preference ,and validation. I just need a way to check if the two values are selected and two are blank..@Tomalak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have change the java-script a bit, just added a flag that can count the number of select is selected with value other than  blank ,if it is grater than 2 then it will return false and Gives a alert message .you should add none option in yous json array.

```
function checkDuplicatesHons(id) {
    var k=10+6*parseInt(id);
   var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select"),
      i,
      current,
      selected = {},flag=0;

  for(i = k; i <= k+3; i++){
    current = selects[i].options[selects[i].selectedIndex].value;//for selecting actual value
    if(current=="")
      flag=flag+1;
  }
  if(flag==2)
  return true;
  else 
    {  alert("Select two subject,Leave 2 blank");
      return false;}
}
```

See the following implementation [check](http://jsbin.com/yisobawofi/1/edit?html,js,output) run with js in bin.

Comment: checkDuplicatesHons() is not executing correctly.@avi

Comment: [seethislink](http://jsbin.com/yisobawofi/1/edit?html,js,output) it is working .there was a problem in jsfiddle library run with js in bin @avi